# Sony Remote API - transferring ARW

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Sony Alpha 7R doesn't support ARW images transfer through Camera Remote API, allowing to download small JPEG previews instead.
Supported features table says ILCE-7R doesn't support that API group. However, there is no such note for ILCE-7R2.
Does it mean ILCE-7R2 allows to transfer ARW images through Camera Remote API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ILCE-7RM2 can transfer ARW images using the Camera Remote API.  Make sure that you have installed the latest version of the Smart Remote Control application on the camera.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Now, the same question concerning HX-400.
Supported features table says HX-400 doesn't support transferring images. However, HX-400 advertisement insists it's possible. What's right?